# C++11 cannot resolve nested namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, nested

say I create a class `Foo` in foo.h under `namespace Fooo` like follows:

```
foo.h:

namespace Fooo {
    class Foo {
    };
}
```

and its corresponding source file:

```
foo.cpp:

namespace Fooo {
Foo::Foo() {
}
}
```

I write another source file `util.cpp` to create some utility functions for the `Foo` class in util.cpp:

```
util.cpp:

namespace Fooo {
    namespace util {
        void helper() {
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the `main.cpp` when I call `Fooo::util::help()`, the compiler gives me the following error:

`error: no member named 'util' in namespace 'Fooo'`

Any thoughts on this? It's really strange to me.

Note: I am using clang++ 3.6 with -std=c++11 supports.

Comment: side issue: you also need to *declare* your constructor `Foo();` in the header file `foo.h`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to declare helper in a .h file and include that file in main.cpp.

The problem is the compilation unit main.cpp hasn't been given a declaration of this function. As far as the compiler is concerned, no such function exists.

Minimally, the compiler needs to know what arguments it takes so it can generate code to call it.

Comment: Thanks! that's indeed the problem!